# Getting timeout error in New Year Chaos problem using scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have got a working scala code for New Year Chaos problem in Hackerrank, but Im recieving timeout errors in some test cases

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

Please help me with optimization of below code:

```
def minimumBribes(q: Array[Int]){
        val c = q.sorted
        var swap = 0
        var count_swap=0
        import scala.util.control._
        val loop = new Breaks
        var temp = 0
        var flag = true

        loop.breakable
        {
            for (i <- q.length-1 to 0 by -1)

            {   
                    swap = 0
                 if (q(i) != i+1)
                 {
                        swap=i-q.indexOf(i+1)
                        if (swap > 2) {println("Too Chaotic");flag=false;loop.break()}
                        else 
                            {
                                temp= q(q.indexOf(i+1))
                                q(q.indexOf(i+1)) = q(i-1)
                                q(i-1) = q(i)
                                q(i) = temp

                                count_swap += swap
                                if(q.deep == c.deep){
                                loop.break()
                                }
                            }
                }
            }            

        }   
        if (flag)println(count_swap)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I don't understand your implementation but

1) `q.sorted` could possibly already run out of time given that `n` is ~10^5.

2) `q.sorted` call is actually redundant since it's just a `1..n` sequence.

3) using `q.indexOf` makes your algorithm O(n^2) complex. It's possible to solve it in linear time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yup I guess indexOf was the possible culprit. Found another way around .

Comment: I'm glad that it helps. I also implemented it myself for the sake of interest. If you a like I can share the code with you.